# Facial Animation for Fuse/Mixamo Character

Tags: animation, rigging

Thank you in advance for any help.  I have created a character with Fuse and I was successful in exporting to mixamo to apply movements.  I can even import my Mixamo fbx into blender no problem.  I would like to add some blinking and some random facial movements to make the character look more alive and less "creepy".  Does anyone have any suggestions on easiest way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you export your character to mixamo a rig is created. When it is finished you can choose if you want your character with facial shapes.
In Blender choose the body of the imported character, in object data you will find a lot of shape-keys. click one  and change it's values. See what happens.
Guenther

Edit - Adobe has since removed the facial Blendshape option.

Comment: The facial shape keys option appears to be gone. Any idea why is was removed?